# db.create_all() not creating tables in Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to create a database table for a user class model using `Flask-SQLAclchemy` and `Postgres`.

**My model class.**

```
from app import db
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(70), index=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(70), index=True, unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(128))
```

**My app initialisation.**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('app.instance.config.DevelopmentConfig')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://postgres:RandomPass@localhost/BrightEventDb'
SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = True
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

**The following info is logged.**

```
2018-01-06 11:53:09,978 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine select version()
2018-01-06 11:53:09,979 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2018-01-06 11:53:09,982 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine select current_schema()
2018-01-06 11:53:09,982 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2018-01-06 11:53:09,984 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test plain returns' AS VARCHAR(60)) AS anon_1
2018-01-06 11:53:09,985 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2018-01-06 11:53:09,986 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test unicode returns' AS VARCHAR(60)) AS anon_1
2018-01-06 11:53:09,987 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2018-01-06 11:53:09,990 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine show standard_conforming_strings
2018-01-06 11:53:09,991 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you were following the flask quick start minimal application, the command worked by default since the `User` class was in the same place as the `db` instance. In your case, however, you will have to import the `User` class as mentioned in the comments `from models import User` into your **app initialization**

Comment: And the trick is to add `from models import User` before `create_all()` because it checks who is inheriting from `db.Model` and creates that tables. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20749534/7919597

Answer (score 4):

As someone in the comments mentioned you are not importing your model into your app initialisation module. You could do that as follows

`from models import User`

Answer (score 3):

As per previous comments, besides importing the `db sqlalchemy` object, you have to import **manually** your model like so

```
(venv) $ py -m flask shell
>>> from app import db
>>> from app.models import User
>>> db.create_all()
```

it's not that bad for small app with couple models to import, but it will be really tedious when it comes to work with medium / large app with many blueprints each one has its own models, so you have to import all of them `manually` so you can imagine the amount of typing code in the shell without talking about errors (typos, import modules errors ..), the solution is to use `Shell Context` to load `automatically` all objects:

```
from app import app, db
from app.models import User, Post, Category

@app.shell_context_processor
def make_shell_context():
    return {'db': db, 'User': User, 'Post': Post, 'Category': Category }
```

now in your shell you can manipulate all objects without any hassle

```
(venv) $ py -m flask shell
>>> db
<SQLAlchemy engine=sqlite:///data-dev.sqlite>
>>> User
<class 'app.models.User'>
>>> Post
<class 'app.models.Post'>
>>> db.create_all()
```

Answer (score 0):

Decativate the virtual environment and activate again.

```
db.create_all()
db.session.commit()
```