# FLASK SQLALCHEMY create_all() not working

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I know there is a typical question, but what am I doing wrong?
After set

```
FLASK_APP='safecanyons:app'
flask run
```

the application starts but no one table is created. This is the main script:

```py
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, g
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager, jwt_required
from safecanyons.models.users import User
from safecanyons.v1.users import bp as bp_users
from safecanyons.settings.dev import SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
from psycopg2 import connect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from safecanyons.models.users import User

def create_app():
    # The imports :
    # from safecanyons.settings.dev import SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
    
    # SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "postgresql://{}:{}@{}/{}".format(
    # DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_HOST,DB_NAME
    # ) 
    # 
    # from safecanyons.models.users import User
    # 
    # from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
    # db = SQLAlchemy()

    # class User(db.Model):
    # __tablename__ = 'users'
    
    # id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    # username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    # email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)

    # def __repr__(self):
    #     return '<User %r>' % self.username
      
    uri = SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
    app = Flask('safecanyons')
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = uri
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = True
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)
    from safecanyons.models.users import User

    db.create_all()
  
    jwt = JWTManager(app)
    app.register_blueprint(bp_users,url_prefix='/v1/users')
    return app,db

app,db = create_app()


@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return "<p>Hello, World!</p>"
```

I've tried with the `app.app_context()` but it doesn't work as I expect.
When I go to database to check the users table creation, no one table exists.

Comment: But when you execute `db.create_all()`? You must do it explicitly.

Comment: Inside create_app() method, db.create_db() is called

Comment: When I run flask  I do: export FLASK_APP=‘safecanyons:app’ so I think create_app() is called then. 
Also after your comment I’ve tried to call manually after flask run was raised an also still not working(not creating the models)

Comment: Are you sure that User model definition is imported before create_all(). Becuaeu you have import but also commented code. You can try to put User

Answer (score 2):

You probably have problems with importing `User` model in the right way (because when using `create_app` pattern there is circular import challange, and you are doing strange hack with returning `db` from `create_app`). `User` must be defined before `create_all` call, but `User` to be defined need `db` but also `create_all` need. How to solve it (I may be wrong with file names and project structure):

1. `safecanyons/app.py`

```py
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager, jwt_required
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from psycopg2 import connect

from safecanyons.v1.users import bp as bp_users
from safecanyons.settings.dev import SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI


db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app():
    from safecanyons.models.users import User
 
    uri = SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
    app = Flask('safecanyons')
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = uri
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = True

    db.init_app(app) # init of db is deferred
    db.create_all()

    jwt = JWTManager(app)
    app.register_blueprint(bp_users,url_prefix='/v1/users')
    return app
   
app = create_app()

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return "<p>Hello, World!</p>"
```

2. `safecanyons/models/users.py`:

```py
from safecayons.app import db

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username
```

The other solution is place above code in one file, but model `User` should be defined before `create_all` call.

Similar topics:

- [db.create_all() not creating tables in Flask-SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48125990/db-create-all-not-creating-tables-in-flask-sqlalchemy/48134006)
- [SQLAlchemy create_all() does not create tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20744277/sqlalchemy-create-all-does-not-create-tables)