# Table not created using db.create_all() function in Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I develop a simple Flask app and reform the project following the package structure. Everything works fine before the the reforming. I create the database and table in python shell.

After the reforming, I come into a problem that the database is created but the table not. So when I try to add a user, the table not found error pops up.

**The app structure is:**

[image: Project structure]

The ****init**.py** of the app:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from MyService.config import Config

db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(Config)

    db.init_app(app)
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
        
    from MyService.users.routes import users
    from MyService.admin.routes import admin

    app.register_blueprint(users)
    app.register_blueprint(admin)

    return app
```

The **config.py** class:

```
class Config:
    SECRET_KEY = "oxdte0UGTV0vSpQoxqTZg7kPjGQWaQzi"
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///users.sqlite3'
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
```

The function that add a new user to the database:

```
@admin.route('/login', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = request.form["nm"]
        session["user"] = user
        if User.query.filter_by(name=user).first():
            session["email"] = User.query.filter_by(name=usr).first().email
        else:
            usr = User(user, "")
            db.session.add(usr)
            db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for("users.user"))
    else:
        if "user" in session:
            return redirect(url_for("users.user"))
        return render_template("login.html")
```

The run.py file:

```
from MyService import create_app

app=create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

As you can see in the folder structure, there is a instance folder with the users.sqlite3 database file. The folder and the file are all automatically created after running the app. But I do not know why the table is not created. The error I meet is:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: users
[SQL: SELECT users._id AS users__id, users.name AS users_name, users.email AS users_email 
FROM users 
WHERE users.name = ?
 LIMIT ? OFFSET ?]
[parameters: ('add', 1, 0)]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)
```

Could someone help me with that? Thank you

Comment: I solved it. I add the from MyService.models.User improt User above the app_context() line because it checks who is inheriting from db.Model and creates that table. Thanks for the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48125990/db-create-all-not-creating-tables-in-flask-sqlalchemy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [db.create\_all() not creating tables in Flask-SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48125990/db-create-all-not-creating-tables-in-flask-sqlalchemy)