# SQLAchemy 'No application found. Either work inside a view function or push'

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Ello ello,

I found similar questions on the bug i'm facing, and tried the solutions offered but it didn't work for me.

I'm trying to separate out my models in a different directory and import them into the app.py

When I try to import the db into the python terminal, i'm getting the no application found.

app.py code

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
# from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from routes import test, root, user
from models.todo import db

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://username:pass123@localhost/db'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'thiskeyissecret'
# db.init_app(app)

with app.app_context():
    api = Api(app)
    db.init_app(app)




api.add_resource(root.HelloWorld, '/')
api.add_resource(test.Test, '/test')
api.add_resource(user.User, '/user')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

models

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

class Todo(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Todos'
    id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = db.Column('data', db.Unicode)

    def __init__(self, id, data):
        self.id = id
        self.data = data

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Todo %>' % self.id
```

my file directory looks like

Main_app

- Models

  - Todo.py
- routes

  - some routes
- app.py

Answer (score 5):

Flask-SQLAlchemy needs an active application context.

Try:

```
with app.app_context():
    print(Todo.query.count())
```

From [the flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/appcontext/#purpose-of-the-context):

> Purpose of the Context
>
> The Flask application object has attributes, such as config, that are
>   useful to access within views and CLI commands. However, importing the
>   app instance within the modules in your project is prone to circular
>   import issues. When using the app factory pattern or writing reusable
>   blueprints or extensions there won’t be an app instance to import at
>   all.
>
> Flask solves this issue with the application context. Rather than
>   referring to an app directly, you use the the current_app proxy, which
>   points to the application handling the current activity.
>
> Flask automatically pushes an application context when handling a
>   request. View functions, error handlers, and other functions that run
>   during a request will have access to current_app.

Answer (score 1):

**In a nutshell, do something like this:**

```
from yourapp import create_app
app = create_app()
app.app_context().push()
```

Comment: I was not able to do db.session.add in side the redis queue call function. This helped me to done the job.

Answer (score 0):

It is ok to have `db` initialised in `app.py`

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from routes import test, root, user

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://username:pass123@localhost/db'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'thiskeyissecret'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

api.add_resource(root.HelloWorld, '/')
api.add_resource(test.Test, '/test')
api.add_resource(user.User, '/user')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Then in your `todo.py`

```
from app import db


class Todo(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Todos'
    id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = db.Column('data', db.Unicode)

    def __init__(self, id, data):
        self.id = id
        self.data = data

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Todo %>' % self.id
```

Comment: I tried that earlier as well, and I'm getting no errors. However, in python terminal when I run "from app import db" and then "db.create_all()", my table's aren't created in postgres.

Comment: wait, I got it. I was import db from app, but I should'be done from models.model import db and then run db.create_all()

Comment: When you import db from app you didn't yet reach the models' declarations. Therefore `db.create_all()` won't create any tables. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20749534/552621

Comment: I'm actually having the circular dependency issue rn. I looked at the thread you linked. I'm able to create the table, but, I cannot retrieve the data in a Get request. My app.py file doesn't recognize the model Task

Comment: Where are your views located? how are you importing the models?

Comment: Hey, forgive my ultra noobness being new to Pythong/Flask, but do I need views if i want to use flask as a REST API?

Comment: check out this thread for how my models are being imported. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49102195/flask-sqlalchemy-module-cannot-be-imported-using-circular-dependency

Answer (score 0):

I get a same err
that err reason for just can operation db in viewfunc

```html
def __init__(self, id, data):
        self.id = id
        self.data = data
```

try move that code operation to your viewfunc