# SQLAlchemy not creating tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to setup a database just like in a tutorial but I am getting a programming error that a table doesn't exist when I'm trying to add a `User`

This is the file that errors (`database.py`):

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base


engine = create_engine(
    "mysql+pymysql://testuser:testpassword@localhost/test?charset=utf8",
    connect_args = {
        "port": 3306
    },
    echo="debug",
    echo_pool=True
)

db_session = scoped_session(
    sessionmaker(
        bind=engine,
        autocommit=False,
        autoflush=False
    )
)

Base = declarative_base()

def init_db():
    import models
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

    from models import User
    db_session.add(
        User(username="testuser", password_hash=b"", password_salt=b"", balance=1)
    )
    db_session.commit()

    print("Initialized the db")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    init_db()
```

To init the database (create the tables) I just run the file.
It errors when it creates the test user.

Here is `models.py`:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Numeric, Binary, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

from database import Base


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    username = Column(String(16), unique=True)
    password_hash = Column(Binary(32))
    password_salt = Column(Binary(32))

    balance = Column(Numeric(precision=65, scale=8))

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<User(balance={})>".format(balance)
```

I tried:

- Committing before adding users (after `create_all`)
- Drop existing tables from the database (although it seems like the table never gets committed)
- `from models import User` instead of `import models` (before `create_all`)

Sorry if there are so many simillar questions, I promise I scavenged for answers, but it's always silly mistakes I made sure I didn't make (or atleast the ones I saw).

I am using MariaDB.

Sorry for long post, many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `Base` in `database.py` isn't the same `Base` that is imported into `models.py`.

A simple test is to put a `print('creating Base')` function call just above the `Base = declarative_base()` statement, and you'll see it is being created twice.

Python calls the module that is being executed `'__main__'`, which you know as you have the `if __name__ == '__main__'` conditional at the bottom of your module. So the first `Base` that is created is `__main__.Base`. Then, in `models.py`, `from database import Base` causes the `database` module to be parsed again, creating `database.Base` in the namespace, and that is the `Base` from which `User` inherits. Then back in `database.py`, the `Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)` call is using the metadata from `__main__.Base` which has no tables in it, and as such creates nothing.

Don't execute out of the module that creates the `Base` instance. Create another module called `main.py` (or whatever), and move your `init_db()` function there and import `Base`, `db_session` and `engine` from `database.py` into `main.py`. That way, you are always using the same `Base` instance. This is example of `main.py`:

```
from database import Base, db_session, engine
from models import User


def init_db():

    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

    db_session.add(
        User(username="testuser", password_hash=b"", password_salt=b"", balance=1)
    )
    db_session.commit()

    print("Initialized the db")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    init_db()
```

Answer (score 6):

- Declare Base class once(for each database) & import it to all modules which define table classes (inherited from Base)
- For Base (a metaclass) to scan & find out all classes which are inherited from it, we need to import all the modules where such table classes (inherited from Base) are defined to module where we call Metadata.create_all(engine).

Comment: This was my case.  All models should be imported before calling"Metadata.create_all"

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the relevant model where you call "Base.metadata.create_all". Example below to create user table

```
from ModelBase import Base
from UserModel import User
    
        
def create_db_schema(engine):
        Base.metadata.create_all(engine,checkfirst=True)
```