# how to use create_all() for sqlalchemy orm objects across files

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have declared multiple orm classes in `a.py`:

```py
Base = declarative_base()


class Message(Base):
    __tablename__ = "message"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "stocktwits"}

    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(BigInteger, nullable=False)
    body = Column(String, nullable=False)
    created_at = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    __table_args__ = (
        Index("created_at_idx", created_at),
    )
...
```

I am initializing the database in another file `b.py`:

```py
def init_db(self):
    engine = create_engine(db_url)
    meta.create_all(engine)
    session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()
```

I have two questions about such structure:

First, how can I refer to my orm objects declared in `a.py` when I call the method `meta.create_all(engine)` in `b.py`? Should I use `Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)`? In that case I have to figure out a way to share the `Base` object across files.

Second, I have [read posts about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20744277/sqlalchemy-create-all-does-not-create-tables#:%7E:text=If%20your%20models%20are%20declared%20in%20a%20separate%20module%2C%20import%20them%20before%20calling%20create_all()) importing objects before calling the `meta.create_all()` , since python does not allowed wildcard import within a function, does it mean I have to import all my orm objects individually, like `from a.py import a, b, c, d, ....`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should I use Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)?

Yes - all model classes that inherit from `Base` are registered in its `metadata`, so calling `Base.metadata.create_all(engine)` will create all the associated tables.

> In that case I have to figure out a way to share the Base object across files

```py
from a import Base
```

in `b.py` should be sufficient.  Obviously you should only define `Base` once.

Comment: If only I could have found this rare answer earlier! Wasted more than a day, looking for an idea! Otherwise, I was defining Base() in all my files. I blame the documentation, as I could not find such hint there.