# SQLAlchemy create_all() unable to create new tables

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have flask web app which uses mysql db using flask-sqlalchemy.

I have kept separate utility scripts for DDL creation.

My existing app works perfectly fine but this script is unable to create new table.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from config import connect_strng
    
app = Flask(__name__)
    
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = connect_string

db = SQLAlchemy()

# Added this import just before create_all
from db_models import Test

db.create_all()
db.session.commit()
```

I have defined model inside db_models

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

class Test(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'test'
    
    test_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

My script is finishing with exit code of 0 indicating no errors, but I don't see table getting generated in mysql database.

```
$ python create_table.py 
$ echo $?
0
```

I checked [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20744277/sqlalchemy-create-all-does-not-create-tables) to the similar question but did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by making use of flask's [application context](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/0.12.x/appcontext/).

As sugested by @noslenkwah, you should use db object from single place by defining into single file `database.py`.

Here is my solution.

**database.py**

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
```

**db_models.py**

```
from database import db

class Test(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'test'
    
    test_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

**create_table.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from config import connect_strng
from database import db
    
app = Flask(__name__)
    
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = connect_string


with app.app_context():
    db.init_app(app)
    # Added this import just beore create_all
    from db_models import Test, CrawlStat
    db.create_all()
    db.session.commit()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the same `db` object across your whole app. Importing it where it is needed.

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy() # <--- This is what is causing your issue
# IT should look something more like...
from create_table import db


class Test(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'test'
    
    test_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

However there is a problem with the above suggestion...It will lead to a circular import. To solve that requires restructuring your app a bit. Exactly how to do it is up to you but I'll give you a suggestion.

Create a new file called `database.py` and put your `db` object in there. Then you can do `from database import db` whenever you need `db`.

database.py

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
```

As far as how to structure your app, consider the [application factory](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/patterns/appfactories/) pattern. It takes into account the circular import issue that commonly arises with flask.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had it restructured but despite of that it was not working.
I solved it by using application context.

Comment: Above solution throws an error without application context.
**RuntimeError: No application found. Either work inside a view function or push an application context. See http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/contexts/.**

Comment: I have posted my answer now.