# SQLAlchemy is not creating a table

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have been stuck on this for hours, but SQLAlchemy is creating a database.db in a folder /instance. It does not create any tables in it though, it literally creates an empty file. Thus it gives the error "sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: user"

website/models.py

```
from . import db
from flask_login import UserMixin

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    email = db.Column(db.String(320), primary_key=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(64))
    name = db.Column(db.String(150)) 
    
def __init__(self, email, password, name):
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
        self.name = name
```

website/**init**.py

```
from os import path
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
DB_NAME = "database.db"
 
    
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'h'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f'sqlite:///{DB_NAME}'
    db.init_app(app)

    from .auth import auth
    app.register_blueprint(auth, url_prefix='/')
 
    create_database(app)

    return app

def create_database(app):
    if not path.exists('instance/' + DB_NAME):
        with app.app_context():
            db.create_all()
        print('Created database!')
```

website/auth.py (what im trying to do):

```
def handle_sign_up(form):
    name = form.get('name')
    email = form.get('email')
    password = form.get('password')
    if len(email) < 6:
        flash('Email must be greater than 5 characters.', category='error')
    elif len(name) < 2:
        flash('That is not your name.', category='error')
    elif len(password) < 6:
        flash('Password must be at least 5 characters.', category='error')
    else:
        new_user = User(name=name, email=email, password=generate_password_hash(password, method='scrypt'))
        print("a")
        db.session.add(new_user)
        print('b')
        db.session.commit()
        print('c') # c does not print out
        flash('Account created!', category='success')
        return redirect(url_for('protected'))
```

When I use a DB viewer and create this table manually in the database.db file, the code actually starts working but I don't want to have to manually do that. I've been following this [video tutorial](https://youtu.be/dam0GPOAvVI?t=4362) and cannot figure out why my code decides not to create a table (I even downloaded his zip and his project works). Could anyone give me even a hint as to what I am doing wrong and/or need to do, because I have spent hours trying to figure this out.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Where in your code are you actually adding the User table to the db?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the swift response. From my understanding, when I use create_all() it will create the tables from the models defined (in this case User).

Comment: Are you importing the modules that contain your classes? Otherwise, how will SQLAlchemy know about them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLAlchemy create\_all() does not create tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20744277/sqlalchemy-create-all-does-not-create-tables)